# How to map texture to shape in Slick 2D

Tags: java, slick

I need to map texture to shape. Texture:

[image: Example texture in diamond shape]

This is a example of shapes I need to map texture to:

[image: Mesh example]

Notice that each piece in mesh has exactly 4 point to map texture. Logic is pretty straight forward: Top center edge to top in mesh etc.

I found some methods on Graphics object like texture(...) however these methods cannot handle diamond texture properly..?

I found this method:

```
ShapeRenderer.texture(shape, image, generator)
```

Where generator is:

```
org.newdawn.slick.geom.TexCoordGenerator
```

However I don't understand How It can be used to map the image to the shape.

How to use it? Is there other way?

Comment: If you're not dead set on using Slick, take a look at libGDX; its status is active as opposed to Slick.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't found an API for this in Slick library. So I wrote a class which does it for me (groovy code):

```
class Stretched {

    Shape shape
    Image image

    Stretched(Shape shape, Image image) {
        this.shape = shape
        this.image = image
    }

    void render() {

        TextureImpl.bindNone()
        image.getTexture().bind()
        SGL GL = Renderer.get()

        GL.glEnable(SGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        GL.glBegin(SGL.GL_QUADS)

        GL.glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0f)
        GL.glVertex2f(shape.points[0], shape.points[1])

        GL.glTexCoord2f(1f, 0.5f)
        GL.glVertex2f(shape.points[2], shape.points[3])

        GL.glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 1f)
        GL.glVertex2f(shape.points[4], shape.points[5])

        GL.glTexCoord2f(0f, 0.5f)
        GL.glVertex2f(shape.points[6], shape.points[7])

        GL.glEnd()
        GL.glDisable(SGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    }
}
```

This takes a Shape (polygon w/ 4 vertexes) and map diamond texture to it.